# How to group different functions of a bundle inside a symfony controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, symfony

I am new to Symfony, and I just installed it, I removed the default `AppBundle` and generated my own. Now, I am trying to create an application that aggregates some realstate data in shows it in my site, or in other words,

It will fetch from various realestate sites, apartments that are available for rent and display it.

The problem I have is not technical, but strategical.

As I do not know how to divide the various tasks of my app and group it in a way that makes sense.

To give you some insights, I have those urls in mind for now

```
/                          # index page
/about                     
/contact  
/login
/register
/subscribe                 # subscribe to a newsletter 
/search?q=..               # display search result
/announce/add              # add new apartment for rent
/announce/{id}/{slug}      # unique url for each anounce
/announce/{id}/{slug}/edit # edit announce if submitted by user
```

From this, I am thinking maybe I should map routes to controllers as:

```
/                          DefaultController::indexAction()
/about                     DefaultController::aboutAction()
/contact                   DefaultController::contactAction()

/login                     UserController::loginAction()
/register                  UserController::registerAction()

/subscribe                 UserController::subscribeAction()

/search?q=..               SearchController::searchAction()

/announce/add              AnnounceController::addAction()
/announce/{id}/{slug}      AnnounceController::showAction()
/announce/{id}/{slug}/edit AnnounceController::editAction()
```

So, this is all I can think of at the moment.

Comment: Ok but what do you ask us? You watn us to tell you if you should do 4 Controller or 5?

Comment: I would like to know if there is a flaw in my thinking about structure of the router ~> controller mapping

Comment: You can tell me if anything seems 'off' to you, or feel should be avoided

Comment: If you think it's Ok like this, then should do like this. :)

Comment: @COil haha, is my code really that horrible? :p

Comment: No. Try with this, and when you will your controllers are too big try to think how to improve things. There no magic method. Try and adapt depending on how the code of for application grows.

Comment: That's interesting really, and it makes sense. I just thought there was more into it than what seemed ok to me... I will follow your advice until someone comes up with and another solution

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be aware of the good pratice of symfony. 
It's recommended to use AppBundle as unique bundle. The choice of the controller you're gonna use is not so important from a technical view. It should be coherent in order to find your controller action easily

You can find a lot of good pratices here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html

Comment: Now this doesn't answer the question, does it? I removed AppBundle and created a new one, with its own namespace. The AppBundle isn't unique, it is just a default bundle. Also, I have seen the 'best practices' page, it does not have an answer to my questions

Comment: It's a good pratice to use AppBundle as the name of the unique bundle you use. 
Your question is not clear. Because you seem to have its answer. The way you divided the action between controllers seems to be logical